# Get two click events on gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, onclick

I currently have 2 lines of code that affect the clicking on a row in a GridView.  If I leave either one in place they work by themselves.  If I put both in only the one in `GridView1_RowDataBound` works.  The `GridView1_RowDataBound` method is used to change the selected row in the GridView on click.  The `GridView1_RowCreated` code is used to make a click make an ID of an element on the page become visible.  I really need both.  Is there a way to combine them?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
}

 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setVisible('cfilterpopup')");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

**EDIT :** `OnClientClick` wouldn't work with GridViewRow. You can try the following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setVisible('cfilterpopup');__doPostBack('" + GridView1.ClientID + "', 'Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
}
```

**Explanation:** In the secod line we are changing the attribute to inject our `setVisible()` method and calling the `__doPostBack()`.

**EDIT 2 :**  There are two issues right now:

1. The `cfilterpopup` will be invisible again upon postback.
2. The `Onclick` attribute is wiped out on postback

**How to fix #1 :**

Add a hidden field in markup. Inside `setVisible()` set the hidden fields value to "1". On body `onload` add a method to scan this value and make the part visible/invisble.

Your markup with the javascript may look like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setVisible(itm) {
           document.getElementById('<%=hdnStatus.ClientID %>').value="1";
        }

        function showcfilterpopup() {
            var status = document.getElementById('<%=hdnStatus.ClientID %>').value;
            document.getElementById('cfilterpopup').style.visibility = status == "1" ? "visible" : "hidden";           
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="showcfilterpopup();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="cfilterpopup" style="display:none">
            <p>cfilterpopup</p>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStatus" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the first one.  My mistake when I first tried it I had syntax wrong.  Now when clicking it, it does not set the cfilterpopup Visible but it does set the selectedrow for the GridView.  The code `e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "setVisible('cfilterpopup');");` is not working even when I comment out the other one.

Comment: I have edited my answer. `OnClientClick` wouldn't work with GridViewRow.

Comment: So close.  That does execute both, but not the way I expect.  cfilterpopup becomes visible for a split second and then goes invisible again.

Comment: It is becoming invisible after postback. If you want to keep it's state, you can save the state in a hidden field, on body onload read the status and set the visibility.